# Discord.js Question about getting the user that reacted to the embed {Updated}

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Can someone please help me I am trying to get the user/users that react to my embed and then have the bot edit the embed with the users that reacted. I am new to coding and I have been searching for hours trying to find out how to do it and I cannot seem to do it.

```js
 Client.on("messageReaction", async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();

  if (user.Client) return;
  if(!reaction.message.guild) return;
  
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
      await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(username)
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
      await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(username)
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
      await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(username)
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
      await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(username)
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
      await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(username)
    }
  }
});
```

**Updated Code Working 16/12/2020**

```js
Client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();

  if (user.bot) return;
  if(!reaction.message.guild) return;
  
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `User reacted: ${u.username}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `User reacted: ${u.username}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `User reacted: ${u.username}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `User reacted: ${u.username}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `User reacted: ${u.username}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
});
```

I have update the above you will be able to see both the issue I had and the code that is now working and it will edit the embed description with the users that have reacted to the message / command.

```js
Client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();

  if (user.bot) return;
  if(!reaction.message.guild) return;
  
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `User reacted: ${reaction.emoji}, ${u.username}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `User reacted: ${reaction.emoji}, ${u.username}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `User reacted: ${reaction.emoji}, ${u.username}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `User reacted: ${reaction.emoji}, ${u.username}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `User reacted: ${reaction.emoji}, ${u.username}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
});

Client.on("messageReactionRemove", async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();

  if (user.bot) return;
  if(!reaction.message.guild) return;
  
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `React to this message to join the battle.`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += ``;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `React to this message to join the battle.`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `React to this message to join the battle.`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
       var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.map(user => user)) {
        response += `React to this message to join the battle.`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);
    }
  }
});
```

This is the remove part, I think that I may have done something wrong, but when I remove  the reaction on my 1st account it works fine but then when I try to do it on a second account it will either replace all the usernames with 2x the resonse or it will delete all the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So which one are you specifically struggling with: getting the user that reacted to the message, editing the embed, or both? Since you didn't clarify which of these you are having problems with, or if you are having issues with both, I will explain both below.

First of all, I believe you're using the wrong event. You should be using `messageReactionAdd` instead of `messageReaction`, and I can't find any documentation for a `messageReaction` event on the docs.

For getting the user that reacted to the message, it also depends on whether you want to get all users who have reacted to the message, or just the one that reacted to trigger the `messageReactionAdd` event.

**Getting Only the Single User That Just Reacted**

The event handler you are using has a `user` parameter which contains all of the data for the user, and you can just use that. This gets the user that just reacted to the message:

```
var username = user.username;
```

**Getting All of the Users That Have Reacted**

The `reaction` parameter has a property `reaction.users` which is a Collection of all of the users who have reacted on the message. This gets all of the users who have reacted to this message. You also do not need to use `.then()` since your function is `async`, allowing you to use `await` instead. You can use it like so:

```
var users = await reaction.users.fetch();

var response = "";

//users is a Collection of all of the users who reacted. You can loop through it.
for (var u of users) {
    response += `User reacted: ${u.username}\n`;
}

//'response' is now a String with all of the usernames listed
```

**Getting and Editing the Embed**

Through `reaction.message.embeds`, we can get the embed on the message, alter it, and then edit the message with our altered embed. Here's one way to do that:

```
//Gets the embed in the message
var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];

//Sets the embed's description to the list of users we made in the previous example
//You can change whatever you need to change: the fields, the title, etc.
embed.description = response;

//Updates/edits the message with our new, modified embed
reaction.message.edit(embed);
```

**Putting It All Together**

I am now going to show you what one part of your code might look like, utilizing the previous two examples. For the sake of simplicity, I'm just going to assume you want to get all of the users that reacted, and not just one user. I am also only going to use one of your `if` statements, once again for simplicity. Here's the end result:

```
Client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();

  if (user.bot) return; //user.client is always 'true', use user.bot instead
  if(!reaction.message.guild) return;
  
  if(reaction.message.channel.id === "786271210585456670") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
      var users = await reaction.users.fetch();
      var response = "";

      for (var u of users.array()) {
        response += `User reacted: ${u.username}\n`;
      }

      var embed = reaction.message.embeds[0];
      embed.description = response;

      reaction.message.edit(embed);

    }
  }
  
});
```

Feel free to test this example out, ensure that it works as you intended, and tweak it to best serve your purposes. Note that you will also need to create a separate event handler to listen for the `messageReactionRemove` event if you additionally want to update the embed when someone unreacts to a message.

Relevant resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User

Comment: Thank you so much for your help this worked but I had to change a few things, I will post them below. 

Client.on("messageReaction" Change to Client.on("messageReactionAdd"

"for (var u of users)" Changed to "for (var u of users.map(user => user))" 

The above worked for me however when I tried to add the Client.on("messageReactionRemove" for some unknown reason I am getting double the response when multiple users remove the reaction.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add the `messageReactionAdd` to the final code. Also instead of doing `users.map(user => user)`, you can just do `users.array()` which has the same result. I've updated my answer to include these, thank you for pointing those out. I am not sure why `messageReactionRemove` would be triggering the response twice, but that would probably be a separate question altogether.

Comment: Thank you for that, the only issue I am having now is the remove section. I seem to have it where it will remove the member and it will either replace it with the same response x2 or it will delete all the users and not just the one user that removed the reaction.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why that would be happening. The remove handler should be working exactly the same as the adding handler. There might be something else in your code that is causing that to happen.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was thinking, Either that or It is me just been stupid and done something wrong.